# Button is not added to the specific web page in mozilla extension

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I cannot figure out how to add a button, in mozilla extension.

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
        var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
        btn.appendChild(t);
        //Appending to DOM 
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
               document.body.insertBefore(button, document.body.firstChild); 
        alert("sucess");
    }
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

i don't know what to do with .xul file

Comment: Are you doing this inside your content script? That's the place.

Comment: it worked .. thanks but it does not function inside function :( ... and can u tell me how can i change the position and style of button and how can i define action on click of the button

Comment: You may add inline css styling and use *position: absolute* to place the button whatever you want. Did you try to attach a *click* event handler to get feedback from the button.

Comment: plz tell me that how can i position it in such a way that all other things on page does not move only i can positioned this button

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: Put here the console output

Comment: now i have to build it for mozilla plz help

Answer (score 0):

Only the content script has an access to the page's DOM. So, you should move this code there.

Edit:
Also remove the listening of the *onUpdate* event and directly call the function. The content script is run on every refresh.

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
        var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
        btn.appendChild(t);
        //Appending to DOM 
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
        alert("suceeded");
}
checkForValidUrl();
```

To position the element just use:

```
btn.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px");
```